# VMWare player win 10 guest clock goes into the far future every boot

Tags: windows-10, boot, virtual-machine, vmware

I have an isolated Win10 VMware player VM running on a Win10 host.

Whenever I boot the machine the date usually goes to a couple centuries from now. Sadly the date it goes to is not consistent.

If I go into the UEFI shell pre-windows boot the date makes sense; and if I hardcode the RTC time in the config file I can see that in the UEFI shell on the 1st powerup; but when I reboot it is nutty again.

So either VMware is doing something to the RTC after it leaves the UEFI shell or the windows VM is writing garbage to the RTC.

How do I stop this?

If I could tell Windows to treat the RTC as read only that could probably solve it.

Comment: Did you [install VMware Tools in VMware Player](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1035392)?

Comment: No, it won't install due to isolation settings.

I thought about dropping isolation, installing an re-enabling but not sure if that would break the reason for isolation in 1st place so am avoiding that. Especially since IDK if it would solve issue.

Comment: You can try, it's easy enough to undo if it doesn't work.

Comment: You need Tools installed for the clock to work properly. Back up your machine, reinstall VMware Player and use a NAT or Bridged connection while installing Tools. I have Workstation here and clocks are always accurate.